# @RequestScope does not work. Request mix data

Tags: spring-boot, sap-cloud-sdk

I have built a relatively small Java application based on SAP Cloud SDK/Spring-Boot.

Each request should be unique. That's why I have provided each class I use with @RequestScope (In despair).

Now, when testing with several users in parallel, we noticed that the data is partially mixed.

I can't find any other scopes n the settings/POMs etc.

What else could it be? The cache from the remote system?
I am not doing anything other than loading data from 3 different data, saving/mapping it in a model and then returning it to the requester.

My model header looks like:

```
@Data
@Component
@RequestScope
public class PartnerModel {
```

Comment: It sounds to me as if you are injecting a singleton bean at some point during your operation. Check that all objects you use have session scope. Also your question is very light on information.

Comment: Could you please specify what kind of data is getting mixed up? Is it the current tenant/principal? Also: Do you use any asynchronous operations while processing your users requests?

Comment: Thanks guys. Your two comments were enough to find my problem. I had actually overlooked that I had an asynchronous function that then calls a bean with a session scope.... Something must have got mixed up